# How to make Python's subprocess() interact with input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, subprocess, popen

*(See Edit 1 below for update)*

I need to interact with a menu I wrote in Python 3.
However, whatever I try, I cannot make the `input()` line to be called. 
(It's the last line in the `get_action()` function).

Following is the (boiled down) script I want to interact with from `subprocess()`:

```
$ cat test_menu.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

action_text = """
5. Perform addition
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit
"""

def get_action():
    print(action_text)
    reply = input("Which action to use? ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_action()
```

`subprocess()` based code to interact with `test_menu.py` above is:

```
$ cat tests1.py
import subprocess

cmd = ["/usr/bin/python3","./test_menu.py"]

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                           shell=False,
                           bufsize=0,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for i in range(8):
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    print output.strip()

process.stdin.write('%s\n' % "5")
process.stdin.flush()
```

But, when I run `tests1.py,` it never gets to the `input()` line:

```
$ python ./tests1.py

5. Perform addition [default]
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit
```

**Any suggestions how can I get `subprocess()` to display and interact with the `input()` line (e.g., to display the `Which action to use?` prompt) ?**

---

**Edit 1:**

Following @Serge suggestion, the `subprocess()` is able to display the prompt line, but it still does not display the input (5) I feed the PIPE.

**Changed `tests1.py:`**

```
import subprocess

def terminated_read(fd, terminators):
    buf = []
    while True:
        r = fd.read(1)
        buf += r
        if r in terminators:
            break
    return ''.join(buf)

cmd = ["/usr/bin/python3","./test_menu.py"]

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                           shell=False,
                           bufsize=0,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for i in range(5):
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    print output.strip()

process.stdin.write("5\n")
process.stdin.flush()

for i in range(80):
    output = terminated_read(process.stdout, "?")
    print output," ",
```

Execution:

```
$ python ./tests1.py

5. Perform addition [default]
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit

Which action to use?
```

Comment: In `test1.py` you are reading 8 lines from stdout, but in `test_menu.py` you are printing only 4.

Comment: In the same way that you have to manually print out the contents of stdout (because you used `PIPE`), you need to manually forward anything the user types into stdin.

Comment: @Andrea, It makes no difference how many lines (above 3) I put in the loop, the input() is never reached.

Comment: @Eric, my problem is that I cannot get subprocess to display the `Which action to use? ` prompt.

Comment: @boardrider: it does make a difference. I know because I've tried ;) How are you testing your code?

Comment: I've seen the edit -- if you want to show the prompt, then you must be aware of line buffering and the fact `readline()` reads a line (but `input()` does not write any newline character)

Comment: Are you using python2 to run the code?

Comment: @SergeBallesta,  there is no of course as the OP could have forgot to add parens, also there is a big difference between subprocess in python2 and 3 so I would rather be sure than waste my time writing the wrong code

Comment: @boardriderm what is the next step after  `reply = input("Which action to use? ")` going to be? it is trivial to just get the few lines outputted and to write to the stdin of the subprocess but what are you actually doing next?

Comment: @Padraic, in the real_world (not the boiled down version), The menu item chosen by the user (which I try to simulate) would trigger a certain processing. And yes, I call `tests1.py` from Python 2.

Comment: @boardrider ok then the code I added will allow you to take user input and do whatever you want with it, inp will hold the response, it is just a matter of using it however you like, you can be more specific with what to look for in stdout.readline in your if I just used enumerate as  there are three options

Comment: You might want to check out [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/examples.html)

Comment: Actually, @Eric, that was my first try, and I turned to subprocess() when I couldn't get `pexpect` to work.

Comment: *but it still does not display the input (5)* → stdout is line-buffered by default and `input()` does not flush the output

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `readline` reads a stream until it finds a newline, and that `input("Which action to use? ")` does not print one.

One simple workaround would be to write

```
...
reply = input("Which action to use? \n")
...
```

If you do not want (or cannot) to change anything in test menu, you will have to implement a read with timeout, or read one char at a time until you find either a new line or a `?`.

For example this should work:

```
...
def terminated_read(fd, terminators):
    buf = []
    while True:
        r = fd.read(1).decode()
        buf += r
        if r in terminators:
            break
    return ''.join(buf)

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                           shell=False,
                           bufsize=0,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for i in range(8):
    output = terminated_read(process.stdout, "\n?")
    print(output.strip())
...
```

Passing the answer to subprocess is simple. The hard part is to guess when to answer. Here, you know that you can answer as soon as an input ends in `?`. I changed your test_menu.py to be able to confirm that it correctly get the command to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

action_text = """
5. Perform addition
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit
"""

def get_action():
    print(action_text)
    reply = input("Which action to use? ")
    print("Was asked ", reply) # display what was asked
    if reply == '5':
        print("subtract...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_action()
```

The wrapper `test1.py` is then simply:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["/usr/bin/python3","./test_menu.py"]

def terminated_read(fd, terminators):
    buf = []
    while True:
        r = fd.read(1).decode()
        # print(r)
        buf.append(r)
        if r in terminators:
            break
    return "".join(buf)

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                           shell=False,
                           bufsize=0,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    output = terminated_read(process.stdout, "\n?")
    print(output.strip())
    if output[-1] == '?':
        break

process.stdin.write(('%s\n' % "5").encode())
cr = process.wait()
end = process.stdout.read().decode()
print("Child result >" +  end + "<")
print("Child code" + str(cr))
```

Started with either Python 3.4 or Python 2.7 the output is as expected:

```
5. Perform addition
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit

Which action to use?
Child result > Was asked  5
subtract...
<
Child code0
```

Comment: @boardrider: Here is a sample code that fully controls the subprocess. Please say whether it is enough for you, because as it has a negative score, I will delete it later.

Comment: Just a note: the `encode` and `decode` are here to allow the code to behave the same under Python2 and Python3

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (the main difference is that this stops reading stdout when it encounters the end of the menu):

#### test1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

cmd = ['./test_menu.py']

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, bufsize=0
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
menu = ''
while True:
    output = p.stdout.read(1)
    if output:
        menu += output
    else:
        break
    if menu.endswith('#: '):
        break
print(p.communicate(raw_input(menu))[0])
```

#### test_menu.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
action_text = '''
5. Perform addition
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit
#: '''
sys.stdout.write(action_text); sys.stdout.flush()
inp = sys.stdin.read()
print(inp)
```

Usage:

```
[ 12:52 me@yourbase ~/test ]$ ./test1.py 

5. Perform addition
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit
#: 5
5

[ 12:52 me@yourbase ~/test ]$ ./test1.py 

5. Perform addition
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit
#: 12345
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are planning after but the following will take input and you can do whatever you want with it in  `get_action`:

```
action_text = """5. Perform addition
6. Perform subtraction
Q. Quit"""

def get_action():
    print(action_text)
    inp = input("Which action to use?\n")
    print(inp)
    print("Now do whatever")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_action()



import subprocess

cmd = ["/usr/bin/python3","./test_menu.py"]

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                           shell=False,
                           bufsize=0,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


for  line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line)
    if line.rstrip() == "Which action to use?":
        r = raw_input()
        process.stdin.write(r+"\n")
```

A sample run:

```
5. Perform addition

6. Perform subtraction

Q. Quit

Which action to use?

6
6

Now do whatever
```

Adding a couple of functions:

```
def add():
    return 4+ 6

def sub():
    return 4 - 6

def get_action():
    print(action_text)
    inp = input("Which action to use?\n")
    if inp == "5":
        print(add())
    elif inp == "6":
        print(sub())
    else:
        print("Goodbye")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_action()
```

Outputs:

```
5. Perform addition

6. Perform subtraction

Q. Quit

Which action to use?

6
-2
```

Add:

```
5. Perform addition

6. Perform subtraction

Q. Quit

Which action to use?

5
10
```

Anything else:

```
5. Perform addition

6. Perform subtraction

Q. Quit

Which action to use?

q
Goodbye
```

If you want to write without taking any input from a user, forget r and just write to stdin:

```
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line)
    if line.rstrip() == "Which action to use?":
        process.stdin.write("5\n")
```

Ouput:

```
5. Perform addition

6. Perform subtraction

Q. Quit

Which action to use?

10
```

Comment: Thanks for you code, @Padraic. However, I need `test1.py` to call `test_menu.py`, and supply it with a choice (e.g. 5) on the same line as the input() prompt (I want to simulate a long interactive session). I tried your code, and it does not seem to do that. See also _Edit 1_ in the OP. BTW, the boiled down version I put here comes from a 581 lines script, so rest assured that there *are* other actions once the input is fed to input().

Comment: @boardrider,  so you want to just write directly to the process stdin, not actually take input? if you replace the r with just the process.write then you can simulate input.  Maybe a little more involved example and how you expect it to go would help

Comment: On another note, if you want to continually interact with a process pexpect should really be exactly what you want

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Cool tip about `pexpect`, but can't this be done in the subprocess smodule?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a linux system it's as easy as running the program as follows:

```
printf "5" | python3 "tests1.py"
```

If you have a python script with multiple questions, just answer each one with a "\n" character in between. For example:

```
printf "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | (The command to run your script)
```

Will answer the first question with "1", the second with "2" and so forth.

This solution works for any interactive script on prompt written in any language. For more information on how to use bash to interact with scripts, there's this post I learned from:

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-interactive-prompts

(This is my first answer in Stack Overflow so the format might be a little weird. Anyways, hope I can help anyone going through this problem as I was.)